# Android Layout alignments

Tags: android

I have been working on a soccer project. I want to make live score activity as three horizontal layouts. The first layout displays team one's information, the second layout displays the score, and the third layout displays team two's information.  Here is a screenshot:

I wrapped three Relative Layouts with a Linear Layout.  The Relative Layouts each have horizontal orientation and a weight of 1. My problem is that the third layout is not looking perfect. Here is my XML:

```
<!--  LIVE SCORE  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/livescore_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

    <!-- TEAM LEFT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/fcb_logo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fc Barcelona"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_captain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luis Enrique"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_left_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- LIVE SCORE -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/livescore"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livescore_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="54'"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livescore_text"
            android:layout_below="@id/livescore_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="4 - 2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- TEAM RIGHT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fc Barcelona"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_captain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luis Enrique"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_right_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/fcb_logo"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_right_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Help me make it perfect.

Comment: what do you mean not perfect in this ? can you please explain

Comment: The "Team Right" layout should be aligned right to the view. So that it looks perfect layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set weight sum to your parent linearlayout to 3 and set your child relative layout width wrap_content to 0dp.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/livescore_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20sp"
android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

    <!-- TEAM LEFT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/fcb_logo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fc Barcelona"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_left_captain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luis Enrique"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_left_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- LIVE SCORE -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/livescore"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livescore_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="54'"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livescore_text"
            android:layout_below="@id/livescore_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="4 - 2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- TEAM RIGHT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fc Barcelona"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_captain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luis Enrique"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/greyText"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_right_name"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/fcb_logo"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_right_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried. It's working but the left layout text is split into two lines

Comment: I solved it by adding `android:gravity="right"` for the 3rd layout

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/livescore_container"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- TEAM LEFT -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/team_left"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_left_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_blue"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_left_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fc Barcelona"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_left_captain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Luis Enrique"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryGreen"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_left_logo"
        android:layout_below="@id/team_left_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- LIVE SCORE -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/livescore"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/livescore_minutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="54'"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryGreen"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/livescore_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/livescore_minutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="4 - 2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- TEAM RIGHT -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/team_right"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fc Barcelona"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_right_captain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Luis Enrique"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryGreen"
            android:layout_below="@id/team_right_name"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_right_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_blue"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="30sp"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rightText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Getting the same result